# Format decimal in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have number with folowing format 
12.25564
The format on field in mysql is DECIMAL(12,5). I want to export file from this table and the format on this decimal number is 12.26. How can I formated this number with MySQL in SELECT ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySql Round Method:

SELECT ROUND(12.25564, 2)